# Titanium SQLite Database Migration : Is it possible to manually call the migration.up and migration.down functions in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am working on developing a module for Titanium project. Now I need to call the `migration.up` and `migration.down` call backs from my own function. Is it possible to do ? I tried `migration.down(AnyObject)` and `migration.up(AnyObject)`, but both didn't work.

Also I tried to log the object migration, it is NULL. So any other options to get the call back implementations ?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding the following code to the migration javascript file.

```
Alloy.Globals.migration = migration;
```

And was able to call `Alloy.Globals.migration.up()` from **alloy.js**.

Let me know, if any alternatives available.